# migrate error 'No migration to apply' also not add table in postgresql in django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm trying to create a model for an eCommerce site but after makemigrations when I trying to migrate terminal show "No migration to apply" but when I checked database no new table was there. Please help me.

`

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


# Create your models here.


class Collection(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class ProductCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Brand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Color(models.Model):
    color = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.color


class Size(models.Model):
    size = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.size


class Products(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    for_people = models.ForeignKey(Collection, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(ProductCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField()
    old_price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.FloatField(null=True)
    input_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    update_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Image(models.Model):
    product_name = models.ForeignKey(Products, related_name='pro_images', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/product_img/', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name.name + 'image'
```

`

The below picture of my terminal please check it

[Terminal show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivGBI.png)

Comment: specify the *app_name* to see if the error persists: `python manage.py migrate product`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
python manage.py migrate product
```

After migrate with the specific model name it's worked for me.